# jqgrid with turbogears 2

Tags: turbogears2

I have been recently trying out crudRESTController in TG2.1.
Overall, I found that--
1] The community is helpful.
2] But, it is hard to find a help topic or docs, if I get stuck-up with a particular issue.
e.g. The name of instance of crudRESTController must be a plural of underlying model name.
Otherwise, it won't work correctly. It is nowhere given in their docs.

Hence I am thinking to use jqgrid for crud functionality.

Can anybody please point out whether it would be better to use jqgrid or stick to crudRESTController!
(keeping in mind the control I can have over the code, rapid application development, deployment, speed, etc.

Thanks in advance,

Vineet.

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at [EasyCrudRestController](http://www.turbogears.org/2.1/docs/main/Extensions/Crud/index.html#easycrudrestcontroller) from tgext.crud, it provides an easy way to create working Crud Controllers on the fly. For more deep customization you can tune it as you would with CrudRestController.